# Change the color of button after it is clicked on - tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I have a question about buttons using tkinter. I created a button, but if it is clicked on I want it to change its color. For example,  if the button is  red, it turns to blue and it remains blue after that.
I know that I can use a condition and if the button is clicked, I use `button.configure()` to change his color, but I do not know how this condition looks like.
Sorry if it is an easy question, I was trying to find it by myself and it did not work.

Comment: You can simply change the button color using `.configure()` inside the callback of `command` option of button.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way would be to check what the current color is, and then change color if necessary.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def do_stuff():
    if button.cget('bg') == 'tomato':   # Check current color
        button.config(bg='powder blue', activebackground='powder blue')
    # Do other stuff if you want

button = tk.Button(root, text='Change color', command=do_stuff, 
                   bg='tomato', activebackground='tomato')
button.pack(padx=50, pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I understand , thank you.  This can be use if i want to change its color after execution of the code, but do you have any idea how can i change this code for the case : if i click a button, to change his color, and if i do not click on it, to remain  initial color? I do not know any way to  write that condition, if the button is clicked on

Comment: Hmmmm..., I don't think I understand what you want to happen. If you click the button it changes color and if you do not click on it the original color remains. Is there something I'm mising here?